# Crypto++ exception : "ciphertext length is not a multiple of block size"

Tags: qt, encryption, aes, crypto++

I've been trying to encrypt/decrypt a byte array with Crypto++ using AES encryption but I got this exception :

```
StreamTransformationFilter: ciphertext length is not a multiple of block size
```

The thing is that I'm using PKCS padding so this shouldn't happen.

This is the function I'm having trouble with. Could anyone tell me what exactly I am doing wrong ?

```
void QtAES256::decrypt(const QByteArray& cryptedArray, QByteArray& decryptedArray) const
{
    CBC_Mode<AES>::Decryption cbcDecryption(reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(m_Key.constData()),
                                            m_Key.length(),
                                            reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(m_IV.constData()));

    byte decryptedResult[MAXSIZE];
    ArraySink* arraySink = new ArraySink(decryptedResult, MAXSIZE);

    StreamTransformationFilter stfDecryptor(cbcDecryption,
                                            arraySink,
                                            StreamTransformationFilter::PKCS_PADDING);

    stfDecryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(cryptedArray.constData()), cryptedArray.length());

    try
    {
        stfDecryptor.MessageEnd();
    }
    catch(InvalidCiphertext &e)
    {
        qDebug() << e.what();
    }

    decryptedArray = QByteArray(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(decryptedResult), arraySink->TotalPutLength());

    delete arraySink;
}
```

Comment: How was it encrypted? Is the encrypted input data length an exact multiple of the block size (16-bytes for AES)?

Comment: What is the plain text, key, iv and cipher text? I'm guessing the problem is an earlier truncation. It could occur over a socket or on a file. Also see [crypto++ qt invalidciphertext site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=crypto%2B%2B+qt+invalidciphertext+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Comment: @zaph - jww an you are both right, the issue came from the encryption, the decryption works fine actually.

Comment: @A.LeBreton - `delete arraySink` is not quite correct. The `StreamTransformationFilter` will delete the `ArraySink` since the filter owns it. Take a look at [`ArraySink`](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/ArraySink) on the Crypto++ wiki. Pay particular attention to *"If you overcommit the size of the array..."* and the use of the `Redirector`.

Comment: @jww - Thank you for that precision. I'm marking the question as solved.